# SMART attributes have large values

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have noticed the Reallocation Event Count with my internal hard drive with a data value and a warning about a year ago and it has been increasing ever since. I have also noticed the Raw read error rate, the Seek error rate, Reported uncorrectable errors, temperature, G-sensor, Hardware ECC all have non-zero data values. However I haven't noticed any performance impact throughout the year.

Here is the full SMART test:

http://postimg.org/image/voksexks3/

Please note that this is a Seagate drive and my operating system is Windows 7.

Please tell me where the issue is and what do you recommended, and are these values acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If they don't change, I wouldn't worry about it too much. The drive may have overheated or otherwise glitched once and may be working fine now. But if they're increasing over time, that's a near certain sign of impending failure. Either way, make sure to back up your data. Even a totally perfectly behaving drive can fail at any time.